# How to draw multiple 3d-surfaces in one plot with python matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

I got a xml file with this data structure:

```
        <TurnOnLoss>
            <ComputationMethod>Table and formula</ComputationMethod>
            <Formula>E/(5.3e-5*6.8+1.167e-3)*(5.3e-5*Rgon+1.167e-3)</Formula>
            <CurrentAxis> -10 0 12.04 24.07 36.11 48.14 60.18</CurrentAxis>
            <VoltageAxis> -100 0 600 800</VoltageAxis>
            <TemperatureAxis> -55 25 150 900 1000</TemperatureAxis>
            <Energy scale="0.001">
                <Temperature>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1786 0.4176 0.7548 1.211 1.745</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.2838 0.6296 1.167 1.773 2.553</Voltage>
                </Temperature>
                <Temperature>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1535 0.359 0.6488 1.041 1.5</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.244 0.5412 1.003 1.524 2.195</Voltage>
                </Temperature>
                <Temperature>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1376 0.3216 0.5813 0.9325 1.344</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.2186 0.4849 0.8987 1.365 1.967</Voltage>
                </Temperature>
                <Temperature>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1238 0.2894 0.5232 0.8393 1.21</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1967 0.4364 0.8088 1.228 1.77</Voltage>
                </Temperature>
                <Temperature>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1238 0.2894 0.5232 0.8393 1.21</Voltage>
                    <Voltage> 0 0 0.1967 0.4364 0.8088 1.228 1.77</Voltage>
                </Temperature>
            </Energy>
        </TurnOnLoss>
```

Current is an array of 1x7, Voltage is an array of 1x5 and Temperature is an array of 1x5.
I want to draw 3d plot for energy E(I, V, T), where I, V, E form a 3d plane and five planes are drawn depending on T.
Here are parts of my codes:

```
def plot_energy_loss(current, temperature, voltage, energy, energy_type, title):
    fig = plt.figure(10, 10)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    x, y = np.meshgrid(temperature, current)
    
    for i, temp in enumerate(temperature):
        z = []
        for j in range(len(voltage)):
            energy_surface = np.array(energy[j])
            z.append(energy_surface[i])

  
        ax.plot_surface(x, y, np.array(z), label=f'Temperature {temp}', alpha=0.7)

    ax.set_xlabel('Current [A]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Voltage Drop [V]')
    ax.set_zlabel(f'{energy_type} [μJ]')

    plt.title(title)

    plt.show()
```

```
def turn_on_loss(root, ns, filename):
    # extract data of turn-on loss
    turn_on_loss_data = root.find('.//ns:TurnOnLoss', namespaces=ns)

    if turn_on_loss_data is not None:
        temperature_axis = turn_on_loss_data.find('.//ns:TemperatureAxis', namespaces=ns)
        if temperature_axis is not None:
            turn_on_temperature = [float(temperature) for temperature in temperature_axis.text.split()]

            turn_on_current = []
            current_axis = turn_on_loss_data.find('.//ns:CurrentAxis', namespaces=ns)
            if current_axis is not None:
                turn_on_current = [float(current) for current in current_axis.text.split()]

                turn_on_voltage_drop = []
                voltage_axis = turn_on_loss_data.find('.//ns:VoltageAxis', namespaces=ns)
                if voltage_axis is not None:
                    turn_on_voltage_drop = [float(voltage) for voltage in
                                            voltage_axis.text.split()]
                    # initialize turn on energy
                    turn_on_energy = []

                    for temp in turn_on_loss_data.findall('.//ns:Energy/ns:Temperature/ns:Voltage', namespaces=ns):
                        energy_data = [float(energy) for energy in temp.text.split()]
                        turn_on_energy.append(energy_data)
                    for i, energy_values in enumerate(turn_on_energy):
                        plot_energy_loss(turn_on_current, turn_on_temperature[i], turn_on_voltage_drop,
                                         [energy_values], 'Turn on Energy',
                                         f'{filename} Output Characteristic Turn-on Energy - Temperature '
                                         f'{turn_on_temperature[i]}')
```

But I always get errors like "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" or "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (5, 4) and arg 1 with shape (7, 5)." or "ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional".

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 188, in 
> extract_data_from_xml_file('/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/all_sic_mosfet_plecs_models')
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 184, in extract_data_from_xml_file
> turn_on_loss(root, ns, name)
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 125, in turn_on_loss
> plot_energy_loss(turn_on_current, turn_on_temperature[i], turn_on_voltage_drop,
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 46, in plot_energy_loss
> for i, temp in enumerate(temperature):
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1

So how can I draw different surfaces in one plot without error about arrays?

--------------Update 03.Jan.2024--------------

I changed some codes in plotting function:
from:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(temperature, current)
```

to:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(current, voltage)
```

And also 'for-loop' in data extraction function:

```
                    for temp in turn_on_loss_data.findall('.//ns:Energy/ns:Temperature/ns:Voltage', namespaces=ns):
                        energy_data = [float(energy) for energy in temp.text.split()]
                        turn_on_energy.append(energy_data)
                
                    plot_energy_loss(turn_on_current, turn_on_temperature, turn_on_voltage_drop, turn_on_energy,
                                 'Turn on Energy',
                                 f'{filename} Output Characteristic Turn-on Energy - Temperature '
                                 f'{turn_on_temperature}')
```

But I got a ValueError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 178, in 
> extract_data_from_xml_file('/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/all_sic_mosfet_plecs_models')
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 174, in extract_data_from_xml_file
> turn_on_loss(root, ns, name)
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 115, in turn_on_loss
> plot_energy_loss(turn_on_current, turn_on_temperature, turn_on_voltage_drop, turn_on_energy,
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/XML_Files_Reader.py", line 52, in plot_energy_loss
> ax.plot_surface(x, y, np.array(z), label=f'Temperature {temp}', alpha=0.7, color=color)
> File "/Users/wenjiehe/opt/anaconda3/envs/Half-Bridge_SiC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1569, in plot_surface
> raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

When I changed the code in plotting function from

```
z.append(energy_surface[i])
```

to

```
z.append(energy_surface)
```

Then there is no error, but I can only plot one surface.

Comment: Where do those errors occur? Please share the full traceback.

Comment: Hi, jared. I have added the Traceback and changes that I've tried in the update.

Comment: Before anyone can help you will need to simplify your code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the shortest possible code that reproduces the error (which should contain everything we need to run the code).